# Can we Use Apache Cassandra instead of JDBC in SpringSocialShowcase

Tags: cassandra, spring-social

I can run this application with no issues with my sql.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase

Can I override the UserConnectionRepository to make this application work with cassandra.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to "override" it, but rather create a new repository that provides the same functionality, but instead of JDBC it can use [Datastax Cassandra driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) for communication with Cassandra cluster. You can then use your new repository in place of the original one. If this project uses dependency injection, it should be 1 line change.

Word of caution, this project is rather basic and contains bad practices. If you just want to get your hands dirty, it's fine, but this is definitely not a good production sample (no error handling, lack of security checks, password stored in clear text etc).

Comment: In fairness, the samples for Spring Social are basic and do not contain those best practices you mention because doing so would distract from their main purpose: To demonstrate Spring Social. You are correct...they are not meant to be production-ready examples. They *are* meant to demonstrate the basics of Spring Social.